# Getting the error 'ClassAssignment' object has no attribute 'assignmentfileupload'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The models that I am using are as followed

```
class ClassAssignment(models.Model) : 
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
    instructions = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    completed = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    due_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())


    def __str__(self) -> str : 
        return self.title



class AssignmentFileUpload(models.Model) : 
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(ClassAssignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to="assignment_uploads/")

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())


    def __str__(self) -> str : 
        return self.assignment.title


    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs) : 
        self.attachment.delete(save=False)
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

The code for the serializer

```
class AssignmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) : 

assignmentfileupload = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='file_uploads',
    many=True,
    read_only = True
)

class Meta : 
    model = ClassAssignment
    fields = (
        'id',
        'classroom',
        'title',
        'instructions',
        'due_date',
        'created_on',
        'assignmentfileupload'
    )
```

I am not able to understand where I am doing wrong. Even the documentation says the same thing and I followed it but it is not working as expected.

I made these changes and now It is working Can someone please explain what went wrong earlier
[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onBG8.png)

Comment: Where have you defined view `file_uploads`?

Comment: What am I supposed to pass in view_name ?

Comment: What I am trying to do is I want to retrieve all the file details that are related to the assignment ? What changes am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs

> view_name - The view name that should be used as the target of the relationship. If you're using the standard router classes this will be a string with the format -detail. required.

So you have to provide `view_name` as `AssignmentFileUpload-detail`

Comment: I tried that too but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: As far as I know I have tried almost every solution that I found on google but so far no luck.

Comment: I have an uploaded the screenshot of the code which is working. Can you please explain what went wrong in my earlier approach ?

Comment: I added a related name and made a fileupload serializer and pointed it to the related_name and it started working but i am still confused about the earlier approach which kept bugging me for so long